# How the or condition needs to be selected?

Tags: sql

I came across a interview question, where the scenario was below.

Two tables are there Teacher and bidding

Teacher

```
sid, name, rating, age
25,mark,7,58
58,ann,10,45
45,bob,8,26
```

bidding

```
sid, bid
23,102
58,104
60,115
```

Ask was to find out sid of teachers whose rating is 10 or bid is 104.

What option you would select:

```
1 - select s.sid from Teachers T where s.rating = 10 UNION select b.sid from Bidding b where b.bid= 104
2 - None
```

I selected `none` because in question no where was mentioned that both tables are interlinked with each other. I mean all sids in Bidding table are of teachers only present in teachers table. I would prefer inner join on sids then apply the or condition in where clause.

what you guys would select option if you get this question in interview ?

Comment: Option 1 is quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want to join the two tables and then apply the filtering logic:

```sql
SELECT t.sid, t.name
FROM Teacher t
LEFT JOIN bidding b
    ON b.sid = t.sid
WHERE t.rating = 10 OR b.bid = 104;
```

Comment: yes but this option is not available in answer. what you would select ?

Comment: I'd do a LEFT JOIN, in case a teacher has no bids.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 will return exactly `sid`s of teachers whose rating is 10 or bid is 104.

```
select s.sid from Teachers T where s.rating = 10 
UNION 
select b.sid from Bidding b where b.bid= 104
```

Join would be needed if some other columns of `Teacher` table were requested besides just `sid`.